# "A RenderFlex overflowed by 97 pixels on the right." in Flutter AlertDialog

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have this problem with actions of AlertDialog

```
AlertDialog(
        title: ...,
        content: ...,
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(onPressed: ...,
              child: Text(btn_download)),
          FlatButton(onPressed: ...,
              child: Text('btn_select')),
          FlatButton(onPressed: ...,
              child: Text(btn_qr)),
          FlatButton(onPressed: ...,
              child: Text(btn_cancel)),
        ],
      );
```

When I show this dialog I get this:
[image]

I tried to use Wrap or other scrolling and multi-child widets, but nothing helps.
Found the same issue [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18448), but no answer yet
Does anybody knows how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have access to AndroidStudio to validate my hypothesis, but I'd try something like this:

```
AlertDialog(
    title: ...,
    content: ...,
    actions: <Widget>[
       new Container (
          child: new Column (
              children: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(onPressed: ...,
                  child: Text(btn_download)),
                  FlatButton(onPressed: ...,
                  child: Text('btn_select'))
          ),
       new Container (
          child: new Column (
              children: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(onPressed: ...,
                  child: Text(btn_gr)),
                  FlatButton(onPressed: ...,
                  child: Text('btn_cancel'))
          ),
      ),
    ],
  );
```

**Edit**: this code *works*, but you have to use a width-constrained `Container`, even though it seems that a 75% screen width is somewhat of a sweet spot, since it works both in portrait and landscape mode.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
// This widget is the root of your application.
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
    title: 'Flutter Demo',
    theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    ),
    home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
}
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
final String title;

@override
_MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
int _counter = 0;

Future<Null> _neverSatisfied() async {
    double c_width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.75;
    return showDialog<Null>(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap button!
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return new AlertDialog(
        title: new Text('Rewind and remember'),
        content: new SingleChildScrollView(
            child: new ListBody(
            children: <Widget>[
                new Text('You will never be satisfied.'),
                new Text('You\’re like me. I’m never satisfied.'),
            ],
            ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
            new Container(
            width: c_width,
            child: new Wrap(
                spacing: 4.0,
                runSpacing: 4.0,
                children: <Widget>[
                    new FlatButton(
                    child: new Text('The Lamb'),
                    onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                    ),
                    new FlatButton(
                    child: new Text('Lies Down'),
                    onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                    ),
                    new FlatButton(
                    child: new Text('On'),
                    onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                    ),
                    new FlatButton(
                    child: new Text('Broadway'),
                    onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                    ),

                ],
            )
            )
        ],
        );
    },
    );
}

void _doNeverSatisfied() {
    _neverSatisfied()
    .then( (Null) {
    print("Satisfied, at last. ");
    });
}



@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
    ),
    body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
            new Text(
            'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            new Text(
            '$_counter',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
        ],
        ),
    ),
    floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _doNeverSatisfied,
        tooltip: 'Call dialog',
        child: new Icon(Icons.add),
    ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
}
}
```

Comment: It works even without Container, but this is not best solution for me - to post buttons to Column, especially on landscape. I want to make something like Wrap, but it doesn't work

Comment: Expanded on my answer, added a code for a full sample.

Comment: Thanks, it can be solution. But I have used ConstrainedBox instead of Container, and calculation of width made inside WidgetBuilder, so it changes for different orientation

Answer (score 1):

The `ButtonBar` is not made for so many buttons.

Place your buttons in a `Wrap` widget or a `Column`.

Comment: As I wrote - I tried Wrap - it doesn't help. Column works, but it's not the best solution in landscape